# How to flag a row where any of the variables start with a string contain a substring in R?

Tags: r, substring

I have a data frame in R that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
             a1 = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), 
             a2 = c(8444, 355, 966, 955),
             b1 = c('j1', 'j133', 'gf42', 'j2'), 
             b2 = c( 'j5', 'j1.1', 'j6', 'aa3'), 
             b3 = c('j3', NA, 'j156', NA)
             )
```

How do I create a variable named "flag" that assigns 1 to rows that have any of the variables starting with "b" containing the substring "j1", and 0 for none of the "b" variables containing "j1" (i.e., the flag variable should be c(1,1,1,0))?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this approach will suit?

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  a1 = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), 
  a2 = c(8444, 355, 966, 955),
  b1 = c('j1', 'j133', 'gf42', 'j2'), 
  b2 = c( 'j5', 'j1.1', 'j6', 'aa3'), 
  b3 = c('j3', NA, 'j156', NA)
)

df %>%
  mutate(flag = if_else(if_any(starts_with("b"), ~str_detect(.x, "j1")),
                        1, 0, missing = 0))
#>   a1   a2   b1   b2   b3 flag
#> 1  A 8444   j1   j5   j3    1
#> 2  D  355 j133 j1.1 <NA>    1
#> 3  A  966 gf42   j6 j156    1
#> 4  C  955   j2  aa3 <NA>    0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>